# Having difficulty in removing Cartesian result from my LINQ statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have following 2 tables

1. Calculator
2. CalculatorPoints

These table are not associated to each other (I mean no PK, FK relationship) but they do have a common column which is CalculatorVersionNo. Now when I am running the following LINQ statement, it return a Cartesian product that is not the right result. Could please anyone be able to assist me how not to have the Cartesian result

```
from cp in db.CalculatorPoints
join pbc in db.Calculators on cp.CalculatorVersionNo equals pbc.CalculatorVersionNo
where cp.DealId == dealId
select new CalculatorAndPoints {}
```

Calculator table output

```
Id  DocumentNumber  MinimumTerm BaseUnits   NewCustomer CalculatorVersionNo
283 340                    3      10              2          1
284 342                    0       0              0          1
285 422                    3       4              2          1
```

CalculatorPoints table output

```
ID  DealId  SelectedPoints  CalculatorVersionNo
1   2344        0                     1
2   2344        0                     1
3   2344        0                     1
```

The result I am getting 9 rows while I just want to combine above 2 result sets on the basisi of CalculatorVersionNo so that I can have 3 rows in out put like as follow

```
Id  DocumentNumber  MinimumTerm BaseUnits   NewCustomer CalculatorVersionNo ID  DealId  SelectedPoints  CalculatorVersionNo
283     340                 3     10              2          1               1    2344   0                1
```

Comment: Well what do you *expect* the result to be? Please provide sample data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Example. Both tables will always have same number of rows (In this scenario 25 in each table). I just want to combine the result of these two tables to get the output in 25 rows while above statement produces 625 rows. In short words above 2 tables have split information and I want to combine them in one object

Comment: Please edit your question (rather than adding comments) with *actual sample data*. (Just 3 rows in each table would be enough.) Your code would only give an N*N result if all the `CalculatorVersionNo` values are the same.

Comment: Yes my CalculatorVersionNo values are same. Can you please advise me how I can get over this issue with current set of data.

Comment: Well if everything is the same, how do you expect to match one input row from each table? LINQ is doing exactly what you asked it to. Combining "on the basis of CalculatorVersionNo" depends on the values of `CalculatorVersionNo` distinguishing the rows from each other.

Comment: Also note that Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL are different things - which are you actually interested in?

Comment: I am after LINQ to SQL

Comment: Right, thank you for removing the EF tag. Now, what associated the row with ID 283 in the first table with the row with ID 1 in the second table? Why isn't it associated with ID 2 instead, for example?

Comment: Thanks for putting me in right direction. Now I can understand where you want me to take. I can use Calculator table Id column as a foreign key in CalculatorPoints table and than by having a join will return me the right result set (i-e one row for each id).

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Basically there has to be something connecting the rows that you want to combine - otherwise it could be *any* combination. (And what you're seeing at the moment is *all* combinations.)